# How to set up right RewriteRule in Apache2 ?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Please help, I have this:

```
<virtualhost *:80>ServerName www.my_domain.ru 
ServerAlias my_domain.ru *.my_domain.ru 
ServerSignature Off
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my_domain\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://$1.my_domain.ru/$2 [R=301,L]



VirtualDocumentRoot /var/%1
ErrorLog /var/log/my_domain.ru/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/my_domain.ru/access.log combined
ServerSignature On
Options FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews ExecCGI
UseCanonicalName Off
</virtualhost>
```

But all my sudomains collected inside /var/info/sub1...sub99 (all names a dynamic)

How to make right alias or Rewrite Rule to send Apache look at /var/info/(here_subdamains_folders)
instead /var/(here_subdamains_folders) ?

Thanks !!!